# pointer to a class type about initialization

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B{
public:
    int date;
    B(){cout<<"B()"<<endl;}
    B(int a){date=a;cout<<"B(int a)"<<endl;}
    B(const B& b){
        date=b.date;
        cout<<"int date;"<<endl;
    }
    B& operator =(const B& b){
        date=b.date;
        cout<<"operator(const B& b)"<<endl;
        return *this;
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout<<date<<std::endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    B a(1);//use B(int a)
    B* b;
    B* c;
    *b=a;//use operator(const B& b)
    *c=*b;//but this one is wrong,why?,I think it also use operator(const B& b)
    new (c)B(*b);
    return 0;
}
```

When I use `*c=*b` it doesn't work, I think it also uses `operator(const B& b)`, but when I use `new(c)B(*b)` it is ok.

What is the difference between `*c=*b` and `new(c)B(*b)` and why is `*c=*b` wrong?

Comment: How it _doesn't work_ exactly? Your pointers aren't initialised at that point, which might cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: *All* the expressions using the pointers `b` and `c` leads to *undefined behavior*, because `b` and `c` are *uninitialized*.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
B* b;
B* c;
```

Now `b` and `c` are unitialized, which means that it is unknown to what memory address they are pointing to.

When you do:

```
*b = a;
```

It changes the value at that unknown address to the value of a.  Which causes `undefined behavior`.

Then you do:

```
*c = *b;
```

Which basically sets value at unknown address `c` to value of unknown address `b` which at this point 'might' still be value of `a`, but it is unknown.

The reason why

```
new (c)B(*b);
```

is working, is the dark magic of `undefined behavior`.

Comment: "Dark magic", since the powers that be are just as likely to turn on you :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Corrected post :D